# PHP Multi-User Session Timeout Management

Tags: php, session, multi-user

I'm implementing a multi-user system , with specific inactivity timeout setting for each user.

given that :

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',$Expire);
```

needs to be called each time before

```
session_start();
```

So, Upon successful login i store the login time using

```
$Expire = time() + $Period ;
apc_store('Expire', $Expire);
```

and in each script start i use

```
$Expire = apc_fetch('Expire') - Time() ;
```

to compare with the user expire setting

This works for a single user, but with multi-user, since one variable stores the expire period , it will be overwritten if more than one user online
even storing a variable for each user will not work, as before session_start() i don't know the user

any ideas?

Comment: Keep the time they last did anything on the client and your server. When the information comes in, compare the time and see if the timeout has expired. if it has do the cleanup. i.e. clear the session variables, destroy the session and cookies. I think the 'garbage collection' thing is a 'red herring'.

Comment: Ryan , i already do keep tracking of time and on timeout i expire the session - i believe the solution you are providing here is to identify the user through client side cookie, but it is a security risk